# Blank screen after first login 13.04; mouse visible

Tags: login, screen

Just installed 13.04 32 bit on a thinkpad r32.  I can log in fine, but then the screen goes to a blank (mulitcolored) screen. The mouse pointer works fine, but that is it.

when I move the mouse to the center of the screen, it changes like it is over a text input box (maybe a 'please register' type of thing??) but it is not visible, just the multi colored desktop.  No other icons or anything.  please help (I am a first time linux user).

Answer (score 0):

Enter the command line interface using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and log in with you username and password. Type the command `startx`. Now you can navigate to the system settings and install the appropriate graphics drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Also try adding "acpi_backlight=vendor" to grub configuration. This has fixed issues on hp machines.